# PHP Regular Expression validate pair key:value in string

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of keywords for example: key1, key2, key3 etc...

And I have a string, and I need to determine it valid or invalid. Here are the rules:

1. If the string not contains keywords, it is OK.
2. If the string contains keywords, it must be followed by a colon (without any space), and after that colon must not be empty (accept space after colon but after that is an unempty string)

Example:

- asds asds asdas dasds <-valid (not constain keyword, it is OK)
- asdasd asds asd `key1:asds` <- valid (keyword followed by colon, it it OK)
- asdasd asdsd `key2:asdsd` asd `key1:  asdsad` <- valid  (keyword followed by colon, it it OK)
- asddfs asfasas `key2:     asds` asd `key2` <- invalid  (keyword NOT followed by colon, it is NOT OK)
- asds `key3:sdsd` asdsad `key1:` <- invalid (keyword followed by colon, but after colon is empty, it is NOT OK)
- asds `key2      :asdsd` <- invalid (keyword not followed by colon)

3. If there is colon, but right before it is not a keyword then it is invalid

Example:

- asds asds asd `key1:asdsd` `key2:    assadas` asfsaf <- valid
- asdsd `aaa:bbb` asds <- invalid (right before colon must be a keyword)
- sds asdsad `asdsd      :asdsd` <- invalid (right before colon must be a keyword)

I have tried `/(key1|key2)(?!\:)/` but it does cover all the above requirements. Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily in a single regexp. Do separate checks for each case.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I don't need to do those things in a single regexp. 2-3 or 4 regexps are still fine. Do you have some idea for few of my cases?

Comment: @mickmackusa Then I won't bother writing my answer, you can post that regexp.

Comment: @AiC I haven't optimized the pattern yet, but does this work in 100% of your real cases? https://3v4l.org/1DWvE

Comment: @mickmackusa, yes, it is space-delimited. Example `aaafrom bbb` is valid, but `aaa from bbb` is invalid. Because it containes the key and not follow by the rules.

Comment: @mickmackusa, you saved my life. Yes, it works in 100% of my real cases. Thank you very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

- The pattern must match the entire string from start to finish.
- The pattern must identify your whitelisted keywords if they occur and immediately disqualify the string as soon as your requirements are not satisfied.
- Extend your list of whitelisted keywords by appending a pipe then the next desired word.
  The pattern isn't so much hunting for "bad" substrings, it is trying to deem every character in the string as "good" -- it just quits when it isn't happy.

Pattern:

```
/                     #starting pattern delimiter
^                     #match start of the string
(?:                   #non-capturing group 
   ?                  #match zero or one literal space character (there is a space before the ?)
  (?:                 #non-capturing group
    \b(?:key1|key2)   #word boundary to ensure matching a full keyword from list
    (?:               #non-capturing group 3
      : *\S+          #match colon, zero or more spaces, then one or more non-whitespace characters
      |               #or
      (*SKIP)(*FAIL)  #instantly deem the string invalid if not satisfying first branch
    )                 #close non-capturing group 3
    |                 #or
    [^: ]+            #match one or more non-colon, non-space characters
  )                   #close non-capturing group 2
)*                    #close non-capturing group 1 and allow zero or more repetitions
$                     #match the end of the string
/                     #end of pattern delimiter
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qbS58))

```
echo preg_match(
         '/^(?: ?(?:\b(?:key1|key2)(?:: *\S+|(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|[^: ]+))*$/',
         $string,
         $m
     )
     ? 'valid'
     : 'invalid';
```

There will be several ways to code a solution for this task (such as using the `\G` metacharacter).  The above pattern is just one way.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa,
Can I ask you for one more help?
I need to show the validation error message to frontend. How can I take the error keys? Such as: key1, key2 if they got errors.
And in case invalid key such as aaa:bbb, how can I take "aaa"?
Could you please take a look?

Comment: Hmm... I suppose then you would need to run a separate `preg_match()` call in the "invalid" conditional branch of my snippet and look for substring signatures that contain colons, but did not qualify.  Have a try with that hint.  Post a new question if you cannot manage it.

Comment: Or instead of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, you could capture the disqualified string.  If there is a captured string as `$m[1]` then the validation failed and you have the string.

Comment: Or completely invert the logic of the task and only search for invalid strings. https://3v4l.org/HREEu

Comment: hi @mickmackusa. I am going to clarify the requirements and will a new question soon. There are a few more obscure things I need to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, Could you please help me take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120185/php-regular-expression-keyvalue-validation