# PHP Regular Expression key:value validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, text-parsing

I have a list of keywords for example: `key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `key4` ...

And I have a string, **includes free strings and key:value pairs**. I need to determine it valid or invalid. Here are the rules:

1. If the string **NOT** contains keywords => **VALID**
2. The `key` in pair `key:value` should be belong to the keywords list.
3. The `value` in pair `key:value` shold not empty
4. There is no space before and after colon in pair `key:value`
5. **Do not** accept any `key:value` that is not in the keyword list

**Example:**

- `aaa bbb ccc` => **VALID**
- `aaa bbb key1:aaa ccc ddd` => **VALID**
- `aaa bbb key2:aaa key1:bbb` => **VALID**
- `aaa bbb key1 ccc` => **INVALID** (`key1` not follows the rule `key:value`)
- `aaa bbb key1:xxx key2:` => **INVALID** (`key2` not follows the rule `key:value`)
- `aaa bbb key1:  xxx ccc` => **INVALID** (not accept space after colon)
- `aaa bbb key1  :xxx ccc` => **INVALID** (not accept space before colon)
- `aaa bbb aakey1` => **VALID** (`aakey1` is not the keyword)
- `aaa bbb key1aa` => **VALID** (`key1aa` is not the keyword)
- `aaa bbb xxx:yyy zzz` => **INVALID** (Do not accept any `key:value` that the `key` is not in the keyword list)

I have tried [`/^(?: ?(?:\b(?:key1|key2)(?:: *\S+|(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\[^: \]+))*$/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73073306/2943403). It was good but didn't cover case `aaa bbb key1aa`. It got invalid instead of valid.

**ALSO, how can I take the invalid keywords? Because I need to show error message to frontend.**

**Example:** for `aaa bbb key1 ccc`, I need to take the error key here is `key1`. So that, I can show error message to frontend such as: `Key1 is invalid format, please check it again...`.

Please help me take a look.

Comment: I think you need `^((key1|key2|key3):\w+|\b(?!(?2)\b)\w+)(?:\h+(?1))*$`. Please re-check your requirements and examples. Why do you say `aaa bbb xxx:yyy zzz` is valid? `xxx` is not on the keyword list. See **[the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VM4oKf/1)**.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. Yes, my mistake. I just edited the post.
Let me check your solution.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. I just tested your solution. It works fine for all my testcases. But as my second question. In invalid cases, how can I get the error keywords? Could you please take a look?

Comment: There is no way, you need to write a second regex. Like `\b(?!(?:key1|key2):)(\w+):\b`.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. Yes, no problems. Second regex is still good. I don't need all thing at only one regex. Let me test your suggestion.

Comment: I updated the regex in my answer.

Comment: Rather than buying people beverages, Stack Overflow allows you to "accept" an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example data, you want to show the wrong keys. In that case, you can match the wrong keys, and if there is no wrong key the string would be valid.

The pattern to detect wrong keys:

```
\b(?:key1|key2)\b:?(?:\h+|$)|\b(?!(?:key1|key2)\b)[^\s:]+:
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:key1|key2)\b` Match key1 or key2 between word boundaries
- `:?(?:\h+|$)` Match optional `:` and either 1+ spaces or end of string
- `|` Or
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!(?:key1|key2)\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not key1 or key2 to the right
- `[^\s:]+:` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `:` and then match `:`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Sglao/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MmdrL)

Example code:

```
$keywords = ["key1", "key2"];
$escaped = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords));
$pattern = "/\b(?:" . $escaped . ")\b" . ":?(?:\h+|$)|\b(?!(?:" . $escaped . ")\b)[^\s:]+:/";

$strings = [
    "aaa bbb key1 ccc",
    "aaa bbb key1:xxx key2:",
    "aaa bbb key1:  xxx ccc",
    "aaa bbb key1  :xxx ccc",
    "aaa bbb xxx:yyy zzz",
    "aaa bbb ccc",
    "aaa bbb key1:aaa ccc ddd",
    "aaa bbb key2:aaa key1:bbb",
    "aaa bbb aakey1",
    "aaa bbb key1aa",
    "aaa bbb key1aa"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);
    if (count($matches[0]) > 0) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
            echo "Invalid string -->'$m' is invalid format, please check it again..." . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Valid string --> '$s'" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Invalid string -->'key1 ' is invalid format, please check it again...
Invalid string -->'key2:' is invalid format, please check it again...
Invalid string -->'key1:  ' is invalid format, please check it again...
Invalid string -->'key1  ' is invalid format, please check it again...
Invalid string -->'xxx:' is invalid format, please check it again...
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb ccc'
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb key1:aaa ccc ddd'
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb key2:aaa key1:bbb'
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb aakey1'
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb key1aa'
Valid string --> 'aaa bbb key1aa'
```

Comment: Hi, `aaa bbb key1:xxx key2:` should a invalid string, because `key2` doesn't any value.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can look like

```
^((key1|key2|key3):\w+|\b(?!(?2)\b)\w+)(?:\h+(?1))*$
^((key1|key2|key3):\w+|(?!(?2)\b)\w+)(?:\s+(?1))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VM4oKf/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `((key1|key2|key3):\w+|(?!(?2)\b)\w+)` - Group 1:

  - `(key1|key2|key3):\w+` - a word that is a valid key captured into Group 1, `:`, one or more word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!(?2)\b)\w+` - a word that is not a key
- `(?:\h+(?1))*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(?1)` - Group 1 pattern recursed/repeated
- `$` - end of string

To collect keys that are not on your list, you can use

```
\b(?!(?:key1|key2|key3):)\w+(?=:\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VM4oKf/3). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!(?:key1|key2):)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are `key1` or `key2` (etc.) followed with `:`
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=:\b)` - immediately to the right, there must be a `:` followed with a word char.

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew.
About the second thing. It not only `collect keys that are NOT on my list`. I need to collects the keys made the string invalid (includes the key in keylist) . Example:

- `aaa bbb key1:xxx key2:` invalid keys are: `key2`
- `aaa bbb xxx:yyy zzz`, invalid keys are: `xxx`
- `aaa bbb key1:  xxx ccc key2  :aaa`, invalid keys are: `key1` and `key2`

Comment: @AiChau `\b(?!(key1|key2|key3):)\w+(?=:\b)|\b(?1)\b(?!:)|(?1)(?=:\B)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VM4oKf/5).